# ember.js - swap out a nested resource from any route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing, single-page-application

I have routes with nested dynamic segments, for example `/:locale/products/:product_id/items/:item_id` etc nesting. I want to swap out the locale in an action in the locale route. I don't want to transition to the base `/:locale` route when I change the locale.

locale route action:

```
actions: {
  localeChanged: function(locale) {
    var route = this.controllerFor('application').get('currentRouteName');
    this.transitionTo(route, locale);
  }
}
```

This only works when I'm not deeply nested. I would like to avoid implementing the `localeChanged` action in every route to provide the exact models needed for a given route.

**Update 1 - Dirty solution:**

```
actions: {
  localeChanged: function(locale) {
    var routes = this.router.router.currentHandlerInfos;
    var models = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
      var params = routes[i].params;
      for (var param in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(param)) {
          models.push(param === 'locale' ? locale : params[param]);
        }
      }
    }

    var args = models.slice();
    var currentRouteName = this.controllerFor('application').get('currentRouteName');
    args.unshift(currentRouteName);
    this.transitionTo.apply(this, args);
  }
}
```

I say dirty because iterating over `this.router.router.currentHandlerInfos` seems error prone. Is there a better way?

Comment: Does it perhaps make sense to have your `locale` as a query param as opposed to being part of the resources/routes?

Comment: That would definitely make it easier. I don't know if I'm quite ready to concede yet though.

Comment: This is probably dirty too, but how about regex modifying the locale on the entire `location.pathname` if it is always the first part of the path? Would ember handle the full route resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a baseRoute that adds this action. Then all your routes could inherit from this base route. You only have to write the code once, and it's shared accross all routes. For example.

```
App.BaseRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   actions: {
    localeChanged: function(locale) {
     var routes = this.router.router.currentHandlerInfos;
     var models = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
      var params = routes[i].params;
      for (var param in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(param)) {
          models.push(param === 'locale' ? locale : params[param]);
        }
      }
     }  
     var args = models.slice();
     var currentRouteName =  this.controllerFor('application').get('currentRouteName');
     args.unshift(currentRouteName);
     this.transitionTo.apply(this, args);
    }
   }});


App.SomeRoute = BaseRoute.extend();
```